# What is the best way to embed an JS App in a Wordpress Page?

Tags: plugin-development, shortcode

I have a independent and complex form that make some calculations (HTML + CSS + JS). Its like a Financial Loan Calculator.

I need to add it in a site made in Wordpress. Just in a public page so site visitors can use the calculator.

What is the best way to do it, so the calculator can be upgraded easily?

I was thinking in "compress" the Calculator Files in a ShortCode or maybe as a Plugin.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Make the public page a template and then target it with [`is_page_template()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page_template/)

How to create a [page template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/).

in your functions.php something like:

```
function wp_25271() {
    if (is_page_template('page-public.php')) {
        wp_enqueue_script('bootcards', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootcards/1.1.2/fonts/icomoon.svg', array('jquery'), '', true);
    }
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_25271');
```